# Some pictures not shown after I sent my site on a linux server

Tags: html, linux, image, http-headers, windows-server-2008-r2

I Has a Html site that is running fine hosted on windows server 2008

http://www.middleeastsoft.com/vista

I sent this site to the Linux centos with nginx web server on it, but the weird thing is some pictures not load, when I look at get request of these pictures I found browser tried to get these pictures as text/html contentType.

http://www.vistapilates.com/

!! I cannot understand the reason? I save these files with photoshop and sent them again but nothing changes.

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the reason, so I share to if anyone have same problem can use;

the reason was letter casing, linux is sensitive for upper and lower case characters.

my picture file normally was: LOGO-White-Big.png so linux couldnot get it, because in my html file I was trying to get 'logo-white-big.png'.

just change filename or edit html file solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
Linux is case sensitive, as opposed to Windows.